# Configurar directiva location en nginx para multiples apis

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Estoy montando un sitio web con nginx para mis diferentes apis, cada api he tenido que estar dándola de alta en las rutas en el archivo nginx.conf, pero a futuro no quisiera estar editando y agregando una nueva ruta en este archivo cada vez que agregue una nueva api. Mi archivo actual es:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root /var/www/html/backend;
   index index.php index.htm index.html;

   location /api {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php$args;
   }

   location /api2 {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /api2/index.php$args;
   }

   location /api3 {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /api3/index.php$args;
   }

   # Aqui seguire agregando location por cada nueva api que surja y no quiero estar
   # alimentando este archivo, debe poder resolverse con una expresion regular

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_pass php_container:9000;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
```

Necesito saber cual seria la configuración, supongo que seria a travez de una expresion regular.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podemos hacer en este caso es almacenar la locacion entrante a traves de una expresion regular en una variable llamada api, luego puedes utilizar esa variable en el resto del archivo si lo necesitas. Algo asi quedaria:

```
location ~ /(?<api>[A-Za-z0-9]+/g) {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /$api/index.php$args;
  }
```

Si tienes problemas con la expresion regular aca te adjunto una hoja con todas las herramientas que necesitas para armar una buena expresion regular.

Fuente: https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/pdf/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, he probado la expresión que me sugieres y funciona bien cuando invoco a la raíz de la api, pero cuando quiero consumir una ruta de dicha api me regresa error 404. Es decir http://localhost/api4/ funciona sin problema pero http://localhost/api4/miruta no funciona ni tampoco http://localhost/api4/miruta/miotraruta. Saludos

Comment: Maravilloso, recuerda votar si te ha servido la respuesta por favor. En cuanto a lo que me comentas deberias utilizar la tabla que te envie y adecuar la expresion regular dependiendo de los caracteres o la composicion de la ruta exclusiva de tu (s) APIs. Saludos!

Comment: he estado leyendo un poco sobre las expresiones regulares, pero aun no logro crear una que me permita consumir cualquier ruta de cuaqluier api lo cual era el objetivo final, si las agrego una por una en el archivo nginx.conf funcionan todas la rutas de la api sin problema, pero ese no es el objetivo, sino tener un location que permita consumir cualquier ruta sin agregarla manualmente.